# Most efficient way to get all comments for youTube channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to write an app that will get all of the comments for a youTube channel.
I have spent a while looking at the docs and trying out examples but I am still unclear of the best way of doing this.

The [comment Threads List call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) seems to do what I need but it doesn't return any of the actual text of the reply. It only contains details about the comment. It tells me who made it, their youTube channel details and so on but to actually get the comment text I then need to use the [comments list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) call to get the content. I will also have to make 2 calls to that as one only gives me the main comment, to get the replies I have to make another call with the parentId set.

So, the calls I need to make:

1. Get list of channel Ids
2. For each Channel get a list of videos
3. For each video load comment threads
4. For each comment thread load the comment
5. for each comment thread with replies load the replies

This seems like a needlessly complicated and resource intensive way of doing this. Why don't they just include the comment content in the comment Threads call?

Am I missing something??

Comment: Can you please add code or a fiddle to show us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Not really no. This is not a code problem. I know how to make all these calls and deal with the result. The problem is an understanding of what calls I need to make in which order to get all the data I need with the lowest number of calls and the smallest amount of data over the wire.

Comment: @Roaders Even i need something direct/simpler way to achieve this. It looks like too much separation among the resources.

Comment: Did you get any efficient way? I need that.